# Plugin Wordpress Advanced Responsive Video Embedder - Overflow not good in some browsers

Tags: css, wordpress

in my website wordpress i'm using the plugin "Advanced Responsive Video Embedder" to incorporate vídeos.
It's cool but i'm having a little problem since i added to the site an ad page that appears when a visitor enters the site.
It happens that in firefox and opera the ad is in front of the video embed by the plugin so it's cool.
However, in chrome, safari and internet explorer the video embed appears on the front of the ad.

Anyone knows how can i solve this? Is this a problem of the plugin css?

```
.arve-thumbsize {
    width: <?php echo $thumb_width_px; ?>;
    height: <?php echo $thumb_height_px; ?>;
}
.arve-embed-container {
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16/9 ratio */
    padding-top: 30px; /* IE6 workaround*/
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
* html .arve-embed-container {
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    margin-bot\tom: 0;
}
.arce-embed-container div,
.arve-embed-container iframe,
.arve-embed-container object,
.arve-embed-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 97%;
    height: 98%;
}
.arve-thumb-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.arve-nothumb-link {
    display: block;
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.arve-thumb-thumb {
    z-index: 15;
}
.arve-thumb-play {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    width: 40px;
    height: 37px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: -19px;
}
.arve-hidden {
    display: none;
}
.arve-hidden-obj {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Since it works in some browsers i really have no idea what it could be.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `z-index` on:

```
.arve-embed-container iframe, .arve-embed-container object, .arve-embed-container embed
```

I've used [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to pinpoint the culprit. Due to my knowledge I could guess that this was probably a `z-index` problem. Then I checked all the divs to see if they had a `z-index`. I found the div I posted above which had a `z-index` of `5000` on it. I've overridden that by using `z-index: 0!important;`.

Comment: If you explain *how* you found this, the OP won't have to ask similar questions...

Comment: Good point. I've used firebug to pinpoint the culprit. Due to my knowledge I could guess that this was probably a z-index problem. Then I checked all the divs to see if they had a z-index. I found the div I posted before which had a z-index of 5000 on it. I've overridden that by using z-index: 0!important;

Comment: I took the liberty of merging your comment to the Answer. See related discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178045/185667 or this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140040/185667